# Avoid Activerecord relation to be reloaded in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Lats say I have some relation:

```
@active_posts = Post.where(active: true).limit(3) # returns 3 active posts, but there are much more then 3
```

Then I modify some of members of this relation:

```
@active_posts.first.update active: false
@active_posts.size # returns 3, but need 2 remaining
```

How can I get the rest 2 active posts within this relation? When I try to iterate through @active_posts, it is reloaded from db and replace deactivated post with active one. But how can I exactly 2 active posts from this relation, remaining after deactivating third one?

Answer (score 0):

Use scope

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :actived, -> { where(active: true) }
  scope :deactived, -> { where(active: false) }
end

@active_posts = Post.actived # returns 3 active posts
@active_posts.first.update active: false
@active_posts.reload
@active_posts = Post.actived
```

Comment: It is not a case. Because last statement returns again 3 activated posts (db has more then 3 active posts. I should fix my example.

Comment: @Molfar unfortunately Rails is not that smart. It's a good habit not to call #reload and always use a scope.